# Can't open implementation or declaration of toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() in .dart file in intellijIDEA

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, dart

using .dart file in Intellij IDEA
clicking F12 to show Declaration or Ctrl+Alt+B to show Implementation are not working for methods  toUpperCase() or toLowerCase()

they work fine with roundToDouble() and to round()

any ideas how to fix this ?

Edit : below is a screenshot for someone on youtube who could do it !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgVnf.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `String` is not implemented as part of the SDK but instead are runtime specific (the `String` class you see in the SDK are just a `abstract`  class). So if you e.g. are compiling to JavaScript you will use another implementation (properly a directly call to the same method in JavaScript).

In VM the `String` methods are "patched" into the class with this class:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/ea50b03cbee9971a3e3f1cc5c832fc2dfb941654/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/string_patch.dart

But as you can see:

```
  String toUpperCase() native "String_toUpperCase";

  String toLowerCase() native "String_toLowerCase";
```

This two methods are actually implemented by a call into the C++ implementation. So we need to look here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/78df4ac452dd3ba69ac0c78559f6dde51eeeadb2/runtime/lib/string.cc

Where we find:

```cpp
DEFINE_NATIVE_ENTRY(String_toLowerCase, 0, 1) {
  const String& receiver =
      String::CheckedHandle(zone, arguments->NativeArgAt(0));
  ASSERT(!receiver.IsNull());
  return String::ToLowerCase(receiver);
}

DEFINE_NATIVE_ENTRY(String_toUpperCase, 0, 1) {
  const String& receiver =
      String::CheckedHandle(zone, arguments->NativeArgAt(0));
  ASSERT(!receiver.IsNull());
  return String::ToUpperCase(receiver);
}
```

This implementation can be found here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/da9697feb96364360bfaedbb1c661c20bf7a4cb0/runtime/vm/object.cc#L22023

```cpp
StringPtr String::ToUpperCase(const String& str, Heap::Space space) {
  // TODO(cshapiro): create a fast-path for OneByteString instances.
  return Transform(CaseMapping::ToUpper, str, space);
}

StringPtr String::ToLowerCase(const String& str, Heap::Space space) {
  // TODO(cshapiro): create a fast-path for OneByteString instances.
  return Transform(CaseMapping::ToLower, str, space);
}
```

Where the `CaseMapping` can be found here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/da9697feb96364360bfaedbb1c661c20bf7a4cb0/runtime/platform/unicode.h#L170

And so on and on... :)

Comment: thank you sir
but I just edited the post adding a screenshot from youtube for someone who could Ctrl+left click toLowerCase() and went directly to the source code/declaration of it

are we missing something ?

Comment: Can you link to the full video? Your picture does not show it is possible.

Comment: here it is,, sorry video is in arabic,, but he will Ctrl+click it  between 0:55 and 1:00

in this video

https://youtu.be/-SxZjuxeCP0

Comment: Well, I don't know how you have configured your IntelliJ but I can Ctrl+Click on `toLowerCase()` in `"".toLowerCase();` and it gives me the same result as showed in the video.

Comment: But since the implementation are hidden anyway, I think you should instead just set the cursor to `toLowerCase` and click Ctrl+Q to show the documentation instead (which are just parsing the same comment). It will be more meaningful in this case.

Comment: well,, Ctrl+Q dunno why it starts Macro recording

but i just re-tried clicking F12 and it opened the String.dart correctly and magically

I guess intellij IDEA needed restart !

anyways,, thanks alot man

Comment: Ok, I guess there are some keyboard shortcut configuration differences between our machines. Please accept my answer if you think we are done. :)